# AngularJs, $http Interceptor and $interval

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

I think I am using Interceptors incorrectly in AngularJS. I want to use them to change a specific value in the response to a `$interval` so that it increments in the UI.

The idea was to use an Interceptor to hijack the response and insert the `$interval` into the response before it reached the template. Nice idea but it doesn't work.

First issue is that I get errors when trying to reassign a property in the response.

The second is that the Interceptor seems to be called for all requests, this isn't ideal as its only specific responses I need to change. This leads me to believe that Interceptors are for authentication and things that are needed for all requests.

Bearing all this in mind I now know that Interceptors are not the way to go.

How else should I solve this issue of needing to add in an `$interval` for certain values in a response? There a few places that this needs to be done so I want to avoid having insert the `$interval` each time.

**EDIT**

The two answers so far are great, now I have this which works and the values are right now they are reassigned, but the `$interval` is not working. There are no errors, but my `live` value is not increasing each second. Any more help would be great.

I am not entirely sure that this is the right place for the the `forEach` either when iterating over `response.data`. Could that be causing me issues with my `$interval`?

```
var shepServices = angular.module('shepServices', ['ngResource']);

shepServices.factory('SiloInterceptor', function($q, $interval) {
    return {
        'response': function(response) {    
            if(response.config.url.endsWith('/silos')) {
                angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
                    $interval(function () {
                      response.data[key].live = response.data[key].live * 2;
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }

            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2**

My data looks like this in `response.data`

```
0: 
     quantity: 767.5
1: 
     quantity: 77.5
2: 
     quantity: 80
```

I want to add a new element to this array which is an `$interval`, so it ends up like so;

```
0: 
     quantity: 767.5
     live: //increment $interval value here
1: 
     quantity: 77.5
     live: //increment $interval value here
2: 
     quantity: 80
     live: //increment $interval value here
```

The `$interval` is firing as I can see output from `console.log`, but its not registering in the response and incrementing he value shown in the UI. The response array is bound to the `$scope` as a`silos`. So I want to do this in my template and have the `silo.live` value increment every second.

```
<span ng-repeat="silo in silos">
    <p class="label label-default">{{silo.live | number}}</small></p>
</span>
```

**EDIT 3**

This is how I am injecting the Interceptor, its not using the classic `$http` object, but is via a `$resource` in a Service.

```
shepServices.factory('Silo', ['$resource', 'SiloInterceptor',
    function($resource, SiloInterceptor) {
        return $resource("/silos", {word: "@word"}, {
            'query': {
                url:        "/silos",
                isArray:    true
            },
            'forLocation': {
                interceptor: SiloInterceptor,
                url:        "/silos",
                params:     {location: "@location_id"},
                isArray:    true
            },
        })
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fully modify the response in the interceptor. In this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1gt8yup/)**, I intercept the response of a user API to inject your name. Unless you post code, we can't tell you what's wrong in your interceptor.

Code of the interceptor:

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function () {
   return {
    'response': function(response) {
      response.data[0].name = 'Jake N (modified by interceptor)';
      return response;
    }
   }
});
```

Regarding the second issue, you could use the config object so as to modify the response only if it match a url pattern (or using a different condition). Here I modify the http response only if the url contains 'users':

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function () {
   return {
    'response': function(response) {
      if (response.config.url.indexOf('users') > -1) {
          response.data[0].name = 'Jake N (modified by interceptor)';
      }
      return response;
    }
   }
});
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1gt8yup/1/)**

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful. The filter is useful and I can now assign a new value within the response. My only issue now is that the $interval is not working, I have updated my question.

Comment: Apologies, fixed now. My mistake.

Comment: Wrong again, $interval is firing, its just updating the response, presumably because the response is done and gone by that point and I should really be changing the $scope?

Comment: What does `response.data` look like. Is it indeed an object with values that are themselves objects with a `live` property? In the `forEach` you wrote in the edit, `response.data[key]` could be replaced with `value`

Comment: `response.data` is my array of objects returned from a RestFul API call. Changing `response.data[key]` to `value` still gives me static values for `.live`. Even doing `new Date()` for `.live` gives a static value, but if I do a `console.log` in my `$interval` then I can see it firing, even though the DOM is not updating.

Comment: If `response.data` is an *array* then the `forEach` is a bit incorrect. Would be useful to have a sample, and also to know what object is bound to `$scope`

Comment: I have edited my Q and added details about the array in `response.data` as well as more details on how I intend to use that data and the `$interval`

Comment: Thanks for the added details. The `live` value is updating for me in this example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1gt8yup/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work when ported into my project. Suggesting their are other issues, like the `silo.live` or even `silo` is not even bound to the template. Its worth noting perhaps that my `$http` call is via a Service's query method for a RESTful API. Not directly with `$http`

Comment: I have added new code again, thanks so much for your continued help Michael! Its via a custom call called `forLocation` in a service using a `$resource`.

Comment: The problem might come from the interceptor declared in `$resource`. Try first with a 'global' interceptor declared in `$httpProvider` (`$resource` uses `$http`). The second option would be to modify your `$resource` interceptor as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/277/). Notice that the update occurs on `response.resource` instead of `response.data`, and that the interceptor returns `response.resource`.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd method works if I loop over `response.resource`, but only if a return `response`, if I return `response.resource` it errors with *Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*. But, it works!

Comment: Glad you sorted this out!

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the requests you want in the response handler the way it is done in response function of responseInterceptor.

```
module.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', 'someAsyncService', function($q, someAsyncService) {  
    var responseInterceptor = {
        response: function(response) {
            if(response.config.url.startsWith('/api/')) {
              //Do your custom processing here
           }
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            someAsyncService.doAsyncOperation().then(function() {
                // Asynchronous operation succeeded, modify response accordingly
                ...
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function() {
                // Asynchronous operation failed, modify response accordingly
                ...
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

    return responseInterceptor;
}]);
```

Comment: Thats a great help, although I don't think I need the async bit. I have updated my question as the $interval is not working.